# GET and POST request in AXIOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios

i try to post the values to the mongo server and get the values from server with same route.it is working but each and every time i need to reload the page manualy. is it right to do the POST and GET request in same route.

i try to make single page application

```
const createJob = async () => {
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_LIST_BEGIN })
    try {
        const { item, price, stock } = state
        await axios.post('/api/v1/list', { item, price, stock })
        dispatch({ type: CREATE_LIST_SUCCESS })
        dispatch({ type: CLEAR_VALUES })
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 401) return
        dispatch({ type: CREATE_LIST_ERROR, payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg } })
    }
    clearAlert()
}

const getItems = async () => {
    dispatch({ type: GET_LIST_BEGIN })
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/list')
        const { items } = data
        dispatch({ type: GET_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: { items } })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response)
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    getItems()
}, [])
```

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with having POST/GET for the same route. If you can share some code then we would be able to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have shared code.

Answer (score 1):

The `POST` handler in your API should return the newly added record and `createJob()` should add the record to your store. So it would look something like this:

```
const createJob = async () => {
  dispatch({ type: CREATE_LIST_BEGIN })
  try {
    const { item, price, stock } = state
    
    // get the new item returned from API
    const {data} = await axios.post('/api/v1/list', { item, price, stock })
    
    // dispatch an action creator which adds the new item
    dispatch({ type: ADD_LIST_ITEM, payload: { item: data.item } })
    
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_LIST_SUCCESS })
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_VALUES })
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) return
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_LIST_ERROR, payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg } })
  }
  clearAlert()
}
```

Comment: if (action.type === ADD_LIST_ITEM) {
        return {
            ...state,
            items:action.payload.item
        }
    }
is it right?  but still i got same issue

Comment: @kishorekumar I don't know anything about the shape of your store but I would think the `if` clause would look like this:
```
if (action.type === 'ADD_LIST_ITEM') { 
  const {item} = action.payload
  return { 
    ...state, 
    items: {
      ...state,items,
      [item.id]: {
        item
      }
    }
  } 
}
```
Keep in mind, your backend API needs to return the added item for this to work.